# getJSON results in XML parse error?

Tags: jquery, getjson

New to javascript and thought I would try retrieve some information from a database (and eventually graph it I hope!).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Flot Examples</title>
      <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.flot.js"></script>
   </head>
      <body>
      <h1>Test Javascript:</h1>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $.get("http://localhost:8000/activity?starttime=13129788041&endtime=0&hostid=1", function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(i,item){
              document.write(i);
          });
      });
  });
  </script>

   </body>
  </html>
```

The line "http://localhost:8000/activity?starttime=13129788041&endtime=0&hostid=1" returns what I'm looking for if I type it in a browser window:

{"1.313496422E9":[0.21000000000003638,448,12754,1.868579977195076]}

But doesn't work in the javascript.

If I look with httpfox there is an error

application/xml (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)

But if I view the "contents" tab in httpfox I can actually see the data under  I require but there is an XML parse error.

```
<?xml-stylesheet
  href="chrome://global/locale/intl.css" type="text/css"
  ?>
  <parsererror>
  XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul Line Number 1, Column 1:
  <sourcetext>
  {"1.313496422E9":[0.21000000000003638,448,12754,1.868579977195076]} ^
  </sourcetext>
  </parsererror>
```

The NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI seems to be about cross domain issues but I'm working locally on the actual server so should I be able to access the data? Also why is there an XML parse error when I can see the exact data I want in httpfox's "Content" tab?

I'm probably doing something horrendously amateur but any help/thoughts/abuse would be welcome!

Cheers,

Rob.

Comment: It sounds like your server-side script is returning JSON data with a `Content-Type: application/xml` header for some reason. It shouldn't do that. `application/json` would be less likely to trip AJAX libraries up.

Comment: I finally managed to change the script on the server-side and now it is returning Content-Type: application/json and I can see my JSON data in the content tab on httpfox with no errors. However, I'm still getting the NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI error even though I'm on the actual server itself using "localhost" or "127.0.0.1".

Answer (score 1):

Either your json is malformed coming from the server or....you aren't actually using the `jQuery.getJSON` function.  If you want to use `jQuery.get`, you need to specify the json data type as the last parameter.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.get("http://localhost:8000/activity?starttime=13129788041&endtime=0&hostid=1", function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(i,item){
              document.write(i);
          });
      }, 'json');
```

Comment: Hi Trevor, adding 'json' at the end or even using getJSON in the call both yield the same error and situation :-O