# Parse xml with javascript accentuated characters

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I'm receiving this supposedly XML after making a call to a webserver over which I have no control.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sfx_menu>
<ctx_obj_set>&lt;ctx_object_1&gt;&lt;perldata&gt;
&lt;hash&gt;
&lt;item key="@rft.auinit"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="48"&gt;R O&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="55"&gt;W S&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.issn"&gt;0066-782X&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="_stash"&gt;
&lt;hash&gt;
&lt;item key="@rft_id"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="0"&gt;info:pmid/22286365&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/hash&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.year"&gt;2011&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.eissn"&gt;1678-4170&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.place"&gt;São Paulo,&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="@sfx.subcategory"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="0"&gt;Clinical Medicine&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="1"&gt;General and Others&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="@rft.auinitm"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="0"&gt;C&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="55"&gt;S&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="svc.fulltext"&gt;yes&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="@rft_id"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="0"&gt;info:pmid/22286365&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.atitle"&gt;[In Process Citation].&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="sfx.response_type"&gt;simplexml&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="sfx.ignore_char_set"&gt;1&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="req.session_id"&gt;s96D99C8A-3E41-11E2-9D07-B659D85E6AE8&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="ctx_enc"&gt;UTF-8&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.object_type"&gt;JOURNAL&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.issue_start"&gt;5&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.language"&gt;eng&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="sfx.has_full_text"&gt;yes&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.object_id"&gt;954927591345&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.volume_start"&gt;97&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.volume"&gt;97&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="sfx.request_id"&gt;21652172&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.genre"&gt;article&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.pub"&gt;Sociedade Brasileira de Cardiologia.&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.issue"&gt;5 Suppl 1&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="sfx.openurl"&gt;http://sfxhosted.exlibrisgroup.com/epo?    rft.genre=article%2Cchapter%2Cbookitem&amp;amp;svc.fulltext=yes&amp;amp;sfx.response_type=simplexml&amp;amp;id=pmid%3A22286365&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.issue_alphastart"&gt; Suppl 1&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.title"&gt;Arquivos brasileiros de cardiologia&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="@rft.stitle"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="0"&gt;ARQ BRAS CARDIOL&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="@rfe_id"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="@rft.aufirst"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="0"&gt;Antonio&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="1"&gt;Antonio S�rgio de Santis Andrade&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="2"&gt;Jo�o Ricardo Cordeiro&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="3"&gt;Lucas Jos� Tachotti&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="4"&gt;Ricardo Casalino Sanches&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="5"&gt;Tarso Augusto Duenhas&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="6"&gt;Alexandre&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="7"&gt;Alberto&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="8"&gt;Alfredo&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="9"&gt;Auristela Isabel de Oliveira&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="10"&gt;Bertha&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="11"&gt;Camilo&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="12"&gt;Carlos R Mart�nez&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="13"&gt;Cesar&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="14"&gt;Clara&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="15"&gt;Daniel&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="16"&gt;Dany&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="17"&gt;Eduardo&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="18"&gt;Evandro&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="19"&gt;Fabio S�ndoli&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="20"&gt;Fernando&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="21"&gt;Fernando&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="22"&gt;Fernando&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="23"&gt;Fernando&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="24"&gt;Flvio&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="25"&gt;Francisco Diniz Affonso&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="26"&gt;Gilberto&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="27"&gt;Guilherme&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="28"&gt;Henrique&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="29"&gt;Humberto&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="30"&gt;Jos&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="31"&gt;Jos� Carlos Raimundo&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="32"&gt;Jos� Roberto Maldonado&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="33"&gt;Juan&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="34"&gt;Juan&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="35"&gt;Juan&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="36"&gt;L�dia Ana Zytynski&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="37"&gt;Luiz Antonio Ferreira&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="38"&gt;Luiz&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="39"&gt;Marcelo&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="40"&gt;Marcelo Luiz Campos&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="41"&gt;Marcelo&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="42"&gt;Mauricio de Rezende&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="43"&gt;Max&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="44"&gt;Omar&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="45"&gt;Pablo Maria A&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="46"&gt;Paulo de Lara&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="47"&gt;Rog�rio Eduardo Gomes Sarmento&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="48"&gt;Roney&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="49"&gt;Srgio&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="50"&gt;Silvia&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="51"&gt;Solange&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="52"&gt;Tirone&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="53"&gt;Vctor&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="54"&gt;Victor&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="55"&gt;Walkiria&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="@rft.aulast"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="0"&gt;Bacelar&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="27"&gt;Spina&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="28"&gt;Murad&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="29"&gt;Hernández&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="30"&gt;Mangione&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="31"&gt;Brito&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="32"&gt;Murillo&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="33"&gt;Plana&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="34"&gt;Paganini&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="35"&gt;Krauss&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="36"&gt;Moura&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="37"&gt;Carvalho&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="38"&gt;Cardoso&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="39"&gt;Katz&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="40"&gt;Vieira&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="41"&gt;Montera&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="42"&gt;Barbosa&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="43"&gt;Grinberg&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="44"&gt;Villagrán&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="45"&gt;Pomerantzeff&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="46"&gt;Lavitola&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="47"&gt;Leite&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="48"&gt;Sampaio&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="49"&gt;Franco&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="50"&gt;Martins&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="51"&gt;Bordignon&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="52"&gt;David&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="53"&gt;Duré&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="54"&gt;Rossei&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="55"&gt;Ávila&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="sfx.sourcename"&gt;PUBMED&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.jtitle"&gt;Arquivos brasileiros de cardiologia&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.coden"&gt;ABCAAJ&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="existing_ts_ids"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="0"&gt;110976638852341&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="sfx.sid"&gt;pmid&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="@rft.au"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="0"&gt;Bacelar, Antonio Carlos&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="1"&gt;Lopes, Antonio S�rgio de Santis Andrade&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="2"&gt;Fernandes, Jo�o Ricardo Cordeiro&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="3"&gt;Pires, Lucas Jos� Tachotti&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="4"&gt;de Moraes, Ricardo Casalino Sanches&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="5"&gt;Accorsi, Tarso Augusto Duenhas&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="10"&gt;Boer, Bertha Napchan&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="11"&gt;Abdulmassih Neto, Camilo&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="12"&gt;Sánchez, Carlos R Mart�nez&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="13"&gt;Esteves, Cesar Augusto&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="14"&gt;Weksler, Clara&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="15"&gt;Piñeiro, Daniel J&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="16"&gt;Kruczan, Dany David&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="17"&gt;Rossi, Eduardo Giusti&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="18"&gt;Mesquita, Evandro Tinoco&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="19"&gt;de Brito Junior, Fabio S�ndoli&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="20"&gt;Bacal, Fernando&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="21"&gt;Bosh, Fernando&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="29"&gt;Hernández, Humberto Martnez&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="30"&gt;Mangione, Jos Armando&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="31"&gt;Brito, Jos� Carlos Raimundo&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="32"&gt;Murillo, Jos� Roberto Maldonado&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="33"&gt;Plana, Juan Carlos&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="34"&gt;Paganini, Juan Jos&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="35"&gt;Krauss, Juan&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="36"&gt;Moura, L�dia Ana Zytynski&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="37"&gt;Carvalho, Luiz Antonio Ferreira&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="38"&gt;Cardoso, Luiz Francisco&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="39"&gt;Katz, Marcelo&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="40"&gt;Vieira, Marcelo Luiz Campos&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="41"&gt;Montera, Marcelo Westerlund&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="42"&gt;Barbosa, Mauricio de Rezende&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="43"&gt;Grinberg, Max&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="44"&gt;Villagrán, Omar Alonzo&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="45"&gt;Pomerantzeff, Pablo Maria A&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="46"&gt;Lavitola, Paulo de Lara&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="47"&gt;Leite, Rog�rio Eduardo Gomes Sarmento&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="48"&gt;Sampaio, Roney Orismar&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="49"&gt;Franco, Srgio&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="50"&gt;Martins, Silvia Marinho&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="51"&gt;Bordignon, Solange&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="52"&gt;David, Tirone E&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="53"&gt;Duré, Vctor Rojas&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="54"&gt;Rossei, Victor&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="55"&gt;Ávila, Walkiria Samuel&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="@sfx.category"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="0"&gt;Health Sciences&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="1"&gt;Health Sciences&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.epage"&gt;67&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="fetchid"&gt;/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=PubMed&amp;amp;id=22286365&amp;amp;retmode=xml&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.spage"&gt;1&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="@rft.auinit1"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="0"&gt;A&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="51"&gt;S&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="52"&gt;T&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="55"&gt;W&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="@svc.constraints"&gt;
&lt;array&gt;
&lt;item key="0"&gt;getFullTxt&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/array&gt;
&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;item key="rft.pmid"&gt;22286365&lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/hash&gt;
&lt;/perldata&gt;
&lt;/ctx_object_1&gt;</ctx_obj_set>
<targets>
<target>
<target_name>MISCELLANEOUS_FREE_EJOURNALS</target_name>
<target_public_name>Free E- Journals</target_public_name>
<target_service_id>110976638852341</target_service_id>
<service_type>getFullTxt</service_type>
<parser>Bulk::BULK</parser>
<parse_param>jkey=http://www.arquivosonline.com.br/</parse_param>
<proxy>no</proxy>
<crossref>no</crossref>
<note></note>
<authentication></authentication>
<char_set>iso-8859-1</char_set>
<displayer>FT::NO_FILL_IN</displayer>
<target_url>http://www.arquivosonline.com.br/</target_url>
</target>
</targets>
</sfx_menu>
```

Somewhere along the lines the accentuated characters become unparsable. I know for a fact that with a java SAX parser it can be parsed. I just need help to do it in javascript.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance =)

Comment: forgot to say that I'm doing this on the xmlhttprequest:        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
       req.setRequestHeader("Accept-encoding", "utf-8"); and also I'm doing the parsing as so:  parser.parseFromString('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
      // + xml.innerHTML(), "text/xml");

Comment: @DaveJarvis I don't need it in json I need it in XML :p

Comment: @DaveJarvis either way it doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/BMLtA/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "application/xml");
var ctx_obj_set = doc.getElementsByTagName('ctx_obj_set')[0];

var subdoc = parser.parseFromString(ctx_obj_set.firstChild.nodeValue,"application/xml");
```

It reads the content of `<ctx_obj_set>` as a string and parses it into another sub XML document

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TKa9R/ (look at the console F12)

Comment: thank you for your reply! your answer sent me to confirm a stranger problem! I'm not actually having problems while parsing the content per say but somewhere between then and having made the request! which is pretty strange. even if I don't attach a load event listener the error pops up anyway! the firefox error window just says not well formed pointing to the first accentuated character! :(

Comment: I'm getting the error message as mozilla describes it :<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/locale/intl.css" type="text/css"?>

<parsererror xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/xml/parsererror.xml">XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
Line Number 151, Column 1:<sourcetext>
^</sourcetext></parsererror>

Comment: that's very strange did you update your browser and still not restarted? some time (years) ago i remember seeing strange errors with XML in firefox after updating.. a restart had solved it

Comment: it could also be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097559/getjson-results-in-xml-parse-error (seems to be a similar error)

Comment: thank you for your replies. I'm still having the issue after having restarted the browser countless times. Unfortunately I can't upgrade the browser itself since this is a corporate environment I'm stuck with 10.0.11 ESR (which is the latest of this particular fork). It might also be interesting to point that this is happening inside an extension not normal js inside an HTML.